# How to block all bots except google and Bing?

Tags: bots, robots.txt

How to block all bots except google and Bing.
I am using Cloudflare but I am confused, how to do.

I want all bots except these face Cloudflare JS Challenge

Comment: You could allow them by user agent, but anyone can easily set up a bot that just sends requests with the google bot/bing bot user agent.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot, I will Appreciate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple: create file in root directory robots.txt

and add which bot you want to allow or disallow

```
# robots.txt 
User-agent: *
Disallow: /

User-agent: bingbot
allow: /
Disallow: /some-page-for-bingbot/

User-agent: googlebot
allow: /
Disallow: /some-page-for-googlebot/
```